# Rolling mean with ZOO when columns have NA values

Tags: r

I have calculated the rolling mean using data.table and zoo.

Code below: I am calculating this on the artprice column which contains NA rows.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
rollmean1 <- data.table(newdf)
rollmean2 <- (rollmean1)[, paste0('MA',126) := lapply(126, function(x) rollmeanr(artprice, x, fill = NA))][]
```

Output:

```
> head(rollmean2)
     spdate SP500close artprice     MA2      MA3 MA126
1: 19870330     289.20     83.6      NA       NA    NA
2: 19870331     291.70       NA 290.450       NA    NA
3: 19870401     292.39       NA 292.045 291.0967    NA
4: 19870402     293.63       NA 293.010 292.5733    NA
5: 19870403     300.41       NA 297.020 295.4767    NA
6: 19870406     301.95       NA 301.180 298.6633    NA
```

Notice artprice column has mostly NA values, however, I would like to ignore them and still run the rolling average. However, I wouldnt want my artprice data to remove all NAs and for it not to match the date column.

Any ideas on how to achieve? 
I was leaning towards something like this and for it recognize there was NA values but continue with the calculation: (x[!is.na(x)])

```
rollmean2 <- (rollmean1)[, paste0('MA',126) := lapply(126, function(x) rollmeanr(artprice, (x[!is.na(x)]), fill = NA))][]
```

Any insight appreciated.

EDIT: Changed code to use rollapply.

```
> rollmean2 <- (rollmean1)[, paste0('MA',126) := lapply(126, rollapplyr, data=artprice, mean, rm.na = TRUE, Fill = NA)][]
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`((rollmean1), , `:=`(paste0("MA", 126), lapply(126,  :
  Supplied 7491 items to be assigned to 7616 items of column 'MA126' (recycled leaving remainder of 125 items).
> tail(rollmean2)
     spdate SP500close artprice MA126
1: 20170524    2404.39       NA    NA
2: 20170525    2415.07       NA    NA
3: 20170526    2415.82       NA    NA
4: 20170530    2412.91       NA    NA
5: 20170531    2411.80       NA    NA
6: 20170601    2430.06       NA    NA
```

It is throwing this warning message:

```
 Warning message:
    In `[.data.table`((rollmean1), , `:=`(paste0("MA", 126), lapply(126,  :
      Supplied 7491 items to be assigned to 7616 items of column 'MA126'
```

data frame rollmean1 has 7616 rows

```
> nrow(rollmean1)
[1] 7616
```

And nrow of output table:

```
> nrow(rollmean2)
[1] 7616
```

So the rolling calculation is to be performed on a MA126 basis. That means the actual calculation can not begin until line 126 leaving 125 lines not filled at the start of the data set. It is recognizing this fact but still not outputting my desired outcome.

Comment: `rollapplyr(x, width, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA)`

Comment: Ok and how do I use rollapply to my line above?